# Select image depending of language of my site

Tags: javascript, image

Into my view I call static image like this:

```
<img src="/SiteAssets/new_JoinImage.png" class="img-responsive img-center">
```

but I want to select another one when my sitepage have change of "en"(English) format

So my language function are

```
  var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        lang = "English";

    }
```

How can I achieve it? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

**HTML**

```
<img src="/SiteAssets/new_JoinImage.png" class="img-responsive img-center" id="imageOne">
```

**Javascript**

```
    var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > -1)) {
        lang = "English";
        document.getElementById("imageOne").src = "/SiteAssets/AnotherImage.png";
    }
```